# Find a constant so the matrix is negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> -7 &2  &-4 \\ 
>  2& c &1 \\ 
>  -4& 1 &-6 
> \end{bmatrix}$. Find $c$ such that $A$ is negative definite.

What I tried so far is to find minors and that's how I get $c<-15/26$. I guess that there is some way that will give me exact number, hopefully from $\mathbb{Z}$. It works if I take $-16/26$ but I'm looking for an algorithm to solve this problem in general.

Answer (score 2):

We can refer to Sylvester criteria and note that we need

- $\det(-7)=-7<0 \quad \det(-6)=-6<0\quad \det(c)=c<0$
- $\det\begin{bmatrix}
     -7 &2   \\   2& c   \end{bmatrix}=-7c-4>0\quad \det\begin{bmatrix}
     -7 &-4   \\   -4& -6   \end{bmatrix}=26>0 \\\det\begin{bmatrix}
     c &1   \\   1& -6   \end{bmatrix}=-6c-1>0$
- $\det A=26c+15<0$

Therefore the final conditions on $c$ are:

- $c<0$
- $-7c-4>0$
- $-6c-1>0$
- $26c+15<0$

which lead to $c<-\frac{15}{26}$.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I did to get the result I stated under the problem. Guess that's the only way to go then?

Comment: Wait, $-7c-4>0$ ?

Comment: @smiljanic997 Yes we indeed need also that second condition.

Comment: @smiljanic997 I think that in that case it is the most effective way to find the conditions on $c$.

Comment: so if a matrix is negative definite, signs of minors should alternate?

Comment: @smiljanic997 Yes of course, indeed the condition $\det(A)<0$ is also consistent with the signature $(+,+,-)$.

Comment: @smiljanic997 Wait, to solve in that way I think we need to check multiple conditions. I fix that.

Comment: @smiljanic997 We need to check the same conditions for any minor to be sure that the matrix is negative definite. The final conditions on $c$ are: $c<0$, $-7c-4>0$, $-6c-1>0$ and $26c+15>0$.

Comment: errata corrige: $26c+15<0$